# How to use angular observables to retrieve data from API within a repetitive time interval

Tags: angular, observable, angular7

I want to understand observables in a practical example. Assume I want to make API calls every 1 minute as long as the APP is on running state. Currently I am doing it using `setInterval` function as below:

```
ngOnInit() {

    setInterval(val => this.getDataFromAPI(), 60000)

}

getDataFromAPI() {
    this.dataServices.getDataFromAPI().subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.gaugeData = data;
    },
    error =>{
        console.log('error')
    });
 }
```

In the `dataServices` file there is a method 'getDataFromAPI`which is responsible of making the`HTTP` calls.

```
getDataFromAPI
    return this.http.get(this.base_url + this.endPoint, {
        headers: {
            'tokenid': this.tokenId,
            'accountid': this.accountId'
        }, params: { groupId: groupId, date: '2020-10-05T11:30:00-07:00' }
    })
    .toPromise().then(res => {
        return res;
    });
}
```

The above example is working very fine, but as mentioned in this article [Understanding RxJS Observables and why you need them](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-rxjs-observables/). they have a different way to create and use observables with subscriptions. How shall create and use observables in the example I provided?

Comment: It would have been better if you could share the code of `dataServices.getDataFromAPI()` method

Comment: Anyways, you can try to use `repeat()` operator from RXJS inside your service method.
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/repeat

Comment: Have you taken a look at [interval](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval)?

Comment: @Shuvo I updated the question with the code inside the service file. I am using promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `timer` combined with a `mergeMap`.
You already have this observable:

```
const apiCall = this.dataServices.getDataFromAPI()
```

You will have to create an other observable, this will start an observable after 1s and he is gonna emit every 1s:

```
const myTimer = timer(1000, 1000)
```

Create an empty subscription in your component, this will give you the ability to unsubscribe later:

```
sub: Subscription
```

Now you can make your subscription inside `ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const apiCall = this.dataServices.getDataFromAPI()
  const myTimer = timer(1000, 1000)
  this.sub = myTimer
    .pipe(
      mergeMap( () => this.dataServices.getDataFromAPI() )
    )
    .subscribe( data => this.gaugeData = data )
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe when you are finished, or you will have memory leaks:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe()
}
```

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-operators-basics-examples?file=index.ts) if you want to check it out, search for `Custom API call` in the index.ts

Comment: Thank you this made it clear, However I am getting this error `core.js:12501 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined` I tried to console.log(data) and the API is retrieving data. what is the error though?

Comment: @AliAlAmine it has something to do this.gaugeData, you will have to put `this.gaugeData = data` instead of `this.gaugeData.next(data)` , I also edited it in my answer

Comment: @AliAlAmine don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if it helped you, as lots of user still forget to do that =)

Comment: what does `mergeMap()` does? can i use `tap` instead? or `map` ?

Comment: you use merge map if you want to combine two observables, you can use tap too if you want I think tap is gonna create a subscription each time you call `this.dataServices.getDataFromAPI` and that is no good, generally avoid using tap and use it when its absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
gaugeData = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(val => this.getDataFromAPI(), 1000)
}

getDataFromAPI() {
    this.dataServices.getDataFromAPI().toPromise().then((data: any) => {
        this.gaugeData.next(data);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error')
    });
}
```

First assign gaugeData as an observable then call the api on 1sec interval and then pass new value to gaugeData.

Comment: I updated the question. I am using promises in the `dataService` file. as @Shuvo mentioned there is a `repeat` function to use instead of the `setInterval`